# OpenGL equivalent of GDI's HatchBrush or PatternBrush?

Tags: opengl, vb6, gdi, brush, brushes

I have a VB6 application (please don't laugh) which does a lot of drawing via BitBlt and the standard VB6 drawing functions.  I am running up against performance issues (yes, I do the regular tricks like drawing to memory).  So, I decided to investigate other ways of drawing, and have come upon OpenGL.

I've been doing some experimenting, and it seems straightforward to do most of what I want; the application mostly only uses very simple drawing -- relatively large 2D rectangles of solid colors and such -- but I haven't been able to find an equivalent to something like a HatchBrush or PatternBrush.

More specifically, I want to be able to specify a small monochrome pixel pattern, choose a color, and whenever I draw a polygon (or whatever), instead of it being solid, have it automatically tiled with that pattern, not translated or rotated or skewed or stretched, with the "on" bits of the pattern showing up in the specified color, and the "off" bits of the pattern left displaying whatever had been drawn under the area that I am now drawing on.

Obviously I could do all the calculations myself.  That is, instead of drawing as a polygon which will somehow automatically be tiled for me, I could calculate all of the lines or pixels or whatever that actually need to be drawn, then draw them as lines or pixels or whatever.  But is there an easier way? Like in GDI, where you just say "draw this polygon using this brush"?

I am guessing that "textures" might be able to accomplish what I want, but it's not clear to me (I'm totally new to this and the documentation I've found is not entirely obvious); it seems like textures might skew or translate or stretch the pattern, based upon the vertices of the polygon? Whereas I want the pattern tiled.

Is there a way to do this, or something like it, other than brute force calculation of exactly the pixels/lines/whatever that need to be drawn?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for [glPolygonStipple()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonStipple.xml) or [glLineStipple()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineStipple.xml).

PolygonStipple is very limited as it allows only 32x32 pattern but it should work like PatternBrush. I have no idea how to implement it in VB though.

Comment: Just tried it out - that's exactly what I want.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure it's the drawing operation itself that is the bottleneck here? Visual Basic is known for being very slow (**Especially** if your program is compiled to intermediary VM code - which is the default AFAIRC. Be sure you check the option to compile to native code!), and if it is your code that is the bottleneck, then OpenGL won't help you much - you'll need to rewrite your code in some other language - probably C or C++, but any .NET lang should also do.

OpenGL contains functions that allow you to draw stippled lines and polygons, but you shouldn't use them. They're deprecated for a long time, and got removed from OpenGL in version 3.1 of the spec. And that's for a reason - these functions don't map well to the modern rendering paradigm and are not supported by modern graphics hardware - meaning you will most likely get a **slow** software fallback if you use them.

The way to go is to use a small texture as a mask, and tile it over the drawn polygons. The texture will get stretched or compressed to match the texture coordinates you specify with the vertices. You have to set the wrapping mode to `GL_REPEAT` for both texture coordinates, and calculate the right coordinates for each vertex so that the texture appears at its original size, repeated the right amount of times.

You could also use the stencil buffer as you described, but... how would you fill that buffer with the pattern, and do it *fast*? You would need a texture anyway. Remember that you need to clear the stencil buffer every frame, before you start drawing. Not doing so could cost you a **massive** performance hit (the exact value of "massive" depending on the graphics hardware and driver version).

It's also possible to achieve the desired effect using a fragment shader, but learning shaders for that would be an overkill for an OpenGL beginner like yourself :-).

Comment: however will glLogicOp still work with textures? I need to first create a striped texture for example and then map it onto a rectangle for example, however i need to make use of logical operations  (to implement raster operations involving the brush in GDI) and i am not succeeding in that.

Thanks for your help

al

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I've found it! I can make a stencil across the entire viewport in the shape of the pattern I want (or its mask, I guess), and then enable that stencil when I want to draw with that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a texture.  Put the pattern in as in image and turn on texture repeating and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  Is there an advantage to it, though, over what I described I found above (making a viewport-sized stencil of the pattern)? That seems to be working OK, but I'm not sure that it's the best way.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out a [a year or two ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312124/opengl-how-to-avoid-texture-scaling/354140#354140).